# How can I redirect the requests to 'www' subdomain on my apache server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, redirect, web

I want to **redirect a request on my apache server at 'http://example.com' to 'http://www.example.com'**. I have **added as alias but it doesn't work**. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the redirect by adding .htaccess file in your root directory with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will force redirect all requests to www.